# Differentiating uses of "also"?

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, adverbes

In the sentence "she goes to school," I could insert the word "also" in two different places and with a slight adjustment of tone it would mean two separate things:

> She *also* goes to school.

(She goes to school in addition to the other things she does.)

> She goes to school, also.

(She goes to school, too, just like you, the person I'm addressing!)

Now, technically, the second sentence could take on the meaning of the first, but the first would be awkward if you were going for the meaning of the second.

> Also, she goes to school.

(I forgot to mention this about her.)

How can I do this in French using *aussi* or *également* ? How can I specify my meaning? Or would I have to use other words?

---

> She goes to Also School.

(The name of the school is Also School.)

It could happen.

Comment: Sadly, I would translate both your first sentences the exact same way in French, it would be a little hard to distinguish which meaning it really has. "*Elle va aussi à l'école*". Though, to specify the second version, you could say "*Elle va elle-aussi à l'école*", "*Elle aussi va à l'école*" or "*Elle va à l'école, tout comme toi*". For the first version, you could say "*En plus, elle va à l'école*".

Comment: @Sifu C'est marrant, j'aurais inversé le sens pour tes exemples. Serait-ce une différence entre le nouveau et l'ancien continent ?

Comment: @Laure que veux-tu dire? (Si tu parles de mon ordre [2 puis 1], c'est une erreur, et j'avais déjà dépassé le temps d'edit pour le modifier) Habituellement j'aurais fait 1, 2.

Comment: @Sifu Ah, les deux mondes s'accordent donc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> She also goes to school.

```
Elle va aussi à l'école (en plus d'autres choses qu'elle fait).
```

> She goes to school, also.

```
Elle aussi va à l'école (tout comme toi!).
```

or, alternatively:

```
Elle aussi, elle va à l'école.
```

which further reduces the ambiguity. The easiest way to denote the difference, of course, is to add more details and remove all doubt as to which way the sentence should be interpreted.

> Also, she goes to school.

```
Également, elle va à l'école
```

works just as well as

```
Aussi, elle va à l'école
```

Although the two sentences above would also benefit greatly from context to clarify that she goes to school as an addendum to other things that were previously mentioned.

```
Elle va à l'École Aussi
```

The lack of break or comma could be enough to imply that *aussi* stands for the name, although to be completely doubt free, I would suggest going with

```
L'école où elle va se nomme Aussi.
```

Comment: I have to say this is a *really* excellent first answer for someone brand new to SE! Nice use of formatting and nice answer. Welcome to the network!

Comment: LOL I edited your answers to lowercase the name of the school because I'm an idiot and I didn't realize you were answering the last part of my question, which was mostly a joke.

Comment: Yeah I noticed, I considered sending you [this link](http://www.toponymie.gouv.qc.ca/ct/normes-procedures/regles-ecriture/comment-ecrire-nom-ecole.html) to avoid an edit war ;)  - I decided to answer the last part as well because I figured it was be a valid question, and followed with the rest.